# Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress querying relationships

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Having an issue using the `Advanced Custom Fields` `Wordpress` `plugin`. I've got 2 `Custom Post Types`

- pa_supplier
- pa_supplier_product

There is a one to many relationship between a supplier and their products. (One supplier has multiple products). I've got a page displaying a list of my suppliers and when I click on a supplier I am taken to `single-pa_supplier` page where I would like to display a list of the products associated with that Supplier.

I've successfully managed to make a query on this page and display products, but they are not the corresponding ones to the Supplier.

This works: - It displays a list of products with a quantity of 10,000 as expected

```
<?php 
$products = get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'pa_supplier_product',
                'posts_per_page' => '100',
                'meta_key' => 'quantity_per_pallet',
                'meta_value' => '10000',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
?>
```

This does not work: - I was hoping it would display all products that have a supplier called "Cavan Box"

```
<?php 
$products = get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'pa_supplier_product',
                'posts_per_page' => '100',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'supplier',
                        'value' => 'Cavan Box',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            ));
?>
```

I don't know why the second query is not working, I've a field called supplier and it is of type `Relationship`. when I create a product I assign it a supplier. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to have database access? Can you verify that there is an actual meta_key called 'supplier' and there key 'supplier' has a value of 'Cavan Box' ? That's where I would start in the debug process.

Comment: Thanks Howdy_McGee - had a similar problem, using the same query (apart from variables like `post_type` and `meta_query['key']`) as the above second snippet. Indeed found out that my `meta_query['value']` did not occur in the database.